# Изменения стиля textbox в template листбокса

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Начал разбираться с wpf и возник вопрос. Как можно в стиле, например для listview, изменить параметры вложенных контролов, которые находятся в datatemlate?

Например есть следующий темплейт:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}"                  
              AlternationCount="2"
              Margin="5"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.RowSpan="5"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsObservableCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentStudent}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>                        
                    <TextBlock Margin="2"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               Grid.Row="0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                
                            <TextBox BorderBrush="White"">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="FirstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" >
                                         <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                             <DataErrorValidationRule />
                                         </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>

                            </TextBox>

                            <TextBlock Text=" " />
                            <TextBox BorderBrush="White" >
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="LastName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <DataErrorValidationRule />
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               Grid.Row="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text ="Возраст: " />                               
                            <TextBox BorderBrush="White" >
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <DataErrorValidationRule />
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                            <TextBlock Text =" лет" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" 
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text ="Пол: " />
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.StudentGenderObservableCollection, 
                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Gender, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

И стиль к нему:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" 
           TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE" />

            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Хочу сделать в этом стиле изменения для параметров textbox, но не могу понять как. Подскажите как можно реализовать или где почитать.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ, наверное, такой:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="..."> ... </Style> <!-- сюда добавляйте нужный стиль -->
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Style.Triggers>
       ...
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

Если нужно менять стиль на триггере, получается не так изящно. Например, это можно сделать так.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
                    Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Как же быть в случае, когда цвет фона текст бокса должен быть таким же как и у item в листвью???

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов: Тьфу, перепутал с `TextBlock`'ом. `TextBox` вроде бы не «опасен». Удалил ту часть ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Но применяется для всех текстбоксов, а я пытаюсь изменить стиль только у элементов листвью AlternationIndex=1.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов: А, ну так немного сложнее. Сейчас подумаю.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов: Смотрите обновление ответа

Comment: Спасибо!!! Скажите, WPF: Windows Presentation Foundation в : NET 4. 5 с примерами на C# 5. 0, стоит читать эту книгу??? Или есть книги попроще для понимания???

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов: Это Мэтью МакДональд? В [нашем списке литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105) её рекомендуют, хотя я начинал с WPF Unleashed. Посмотрите список, там может быть что-нибудь найдётся для вас.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов: Пожалуйста!